# The intersection $\mathcal{I}=\displaystyle\bigcap_{\mathcal{F}\in \mathcal{E}}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra in $\Omega$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

**QUESTION:** Let $\mathcal{E}\neq\varnothing$ be a collection of $\sigma$-algebras of $\Omega$. Then the intersection $\mathcal{I}=\displaystyle\bigcap_{\mathcal{F}\in \mathcal{E}}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra in $\Omega$.

**ANSWER:** By hypotesis $\varnothing \neq \mathcal{E}$ is a collection of $\sigma$-algebras, this is $\mathcal{E}=\{F\}_i$ of $\Omega$. Thereby:

1. $\Omega\in \mathcal{F}_i\; \forall i\implies \Omega \in \displaystyle\bigcap_{\mathcal{F}\in \mathcal{E}}=\mathcal{I}$.
2. If $\mathcal{A} \in \mathcal{I}\implies \mathcal{A} \in \mathcal{F}_i\;\forall i\implies \mathcal{A}^c \in \mathcal{F}_i\;\forall i\implies \mathcal{A}^c \in \mathcal{I}$;
3. Let $\mathcal{A}_j \in \mathcal{I}$, where $\mathcal{E}=\{\mathcal{F}_i\}$ for every $\mathcal{F}\in \mathcal{E}\; \forall i.$ Then $\mathcal{A}_j\in \mathcal{F}_i, \; \forall i$, moreover we have $\cup\mathcal{A}_j\in \mathcal{F}_i, \; \forall i \implies \cup \mathcal{A}_j\in \mathcal{I}.$

Therefore, for 1, 2 and 3 we have proved that $\mathcal{I}$ is also a $\sigma$-algebra in $\Omega$.

**MY DOUBT:** Is my proof correct?

Comment: Why do you question whether your proof is rigorous? A major purpose of rigor is to make it easy to tell whether what you have said is correct, so it seems perhaps that you may be lacking in understanding how to prove things in general, rather than this specific question about $\sigma$ algebras.

Comment: Ok. I agree. Then  I 've  changed  my  question. Thanks.

Comment: Screw rigor. This proof is fine.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't mean to imply your proof was incorrect! Indeed your proof is correct, though quite terse. Some complete sentences may help the reader significantly. I was just hoping to spur you to ask yourself _why_ you are not sure whether your proof is correct. A proof is something you should be confident in. After all, if the proof does not absolutely convince you of the statement's truth, then how can it be called a proof?

Comment: @nullUser No worries! I understood! Thanks very much for your message.